# hibernate criteria with exists clause

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I cannot find a solution to a problem that seems to be easy. Say there are 2 entity classes:

```
class A {
   Set<B> bs;
}

class B {
   String text;
}
```

How to create a criteria query that returns all A's that contains at least one B entity which fulfills a given condition (like b.text = 'condition')?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I think this link can be useful: 
http://mikedesjardins.net/2008/09/22/hibernate-criteria-subqueries-exists/

It contains the following example about how create n exists criteria:

"What you’re really trying to do is to obtain all Pizza Orders where an associated small pizza exists. In other words, the SQL query that you’re trying to emulate is

```
SELECT *
  FROM PIZZA_ORDER
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM PIZZA
                WHERE PIZZA.pizza_size_id = 1
                  AND PIZZA.pizza_order_id = PIZZA_ORDER.pizza_order_id)
```

The way that you do that is by using an “exists” Subquery, like this:

```
Criteria criteria = Criteria.forClass(PizzaOrder.class,"pizzaOrder");
DetachedCriteria sizeCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Pizza.class,"pizza");
sizeCriteria.add("pizza_size_id",1);
sizeCriteria.add(Property.forName("pizza.pizza_order_id").eqProperty("pizzaOrder.pizza_order_id"));
criteria.add(Subqueries.exists(sizeCriteria.setProjection(Projections.property("pizza.id"))));
List<pizzaOrder> ordersWithOneSmallPizza = criteria.list();
```

And voila, the result will contain two PizzaOrders!"

Comment: Can you please edit your post to include the relevant bits so the answer still has value when the link goes down?

Comment: `Property.forName("pizza.pizza_order_id").eqProperty("pizzaOrder.pizza_order_id")`   pizza_order_id is the class property name or table column name?

Comment: Hibernate 5.0.7 I cant see method `sizeCriteria.add(String,int)`